# JPA Hibernate N+1 Issue Even with Join Fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new to JPA, Java, and Hibernate so please be patient.

I have a JPA repository like so:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<VPLabOrderLite, Integer> {
  @Query(
      "select o from VPLabOrderLite o "
          + "inner join fetch o.stay s "
          + "inner join fetch  s.patient p "
          + "left join fetch o.orderedTests t "
          + "left join fetch t.result r "
          + "where p.id = :maAccession")
  List<VPLabOrderLite> getOrders(@Param("maAccession") String maAccession);
}
```

The issue is that when it comes to the last join fetch on t.result it will spawn a sql query back to the db for every instance of o.orderedTests t.  It seems to be related to the fact that the t.result property has a @JoinColumns attribute on it, because when I change it to a single @JoinColumn attribute the additional queries go away (but the meaning of the join is lost so i need to join on multiple columns)

Here is the result attribute in the OrderedTest entity

```
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "orderNo",
        referencedColumnName = "orderId",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "testId",
        referencedColumnName = "testId",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
 })
  private VPLabTestResultLite result;
```

How do i get rid of the unneeded extra queries?